# is it possible to include a model that doesn't contain a navigation property on the displaying model/viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have 2 classes which I have created a view model for:

```
public class Sweet
{
    public int SweetID { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public string SweetName { get; set; }
    public bool Singular { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
}


public class Cart
{
    [Key]
    public int RecordID { get; set; }
    public string CartID { get; set; }
    public int SweetID { get; set; }
    public int PemixID { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public Sweet Sweet { get; set; }
    public PreMix PreMix { get; set; }

}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class SweetViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Sweet> Sweet { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Cart> Cart { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to display a list of all the sweets including the Qty of each sweet in current cart (the sweet may not exists in current cart).

I have written a basic query of the data I need but unsure how to do this the MVC way:

```
select Sweets.*, Qty
from Sweets
left join (select SweetID,  Qty from carts where CartID = '7125794e-38f4- 4ec3-b016-cd8393346669' ) t 
on Sweets.SweetID = t.SweetID
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SweetTestArea()
{
   var viewModel = new SweetViewModel
   {

       Sweet = db.Sweets.Include(s => s.Carts)    

   };

   return View(viewModel);
}
```

View:

```
@model  WebApplication1.ViewModels.SweetViewModel

@foreach (var item in Model.Sweet)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SweetName)

    //this doesn't work
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cart.Qty)
}
```

Comment: As I guess from your post 
Is you want linq or lambda expression query for your sql query?

Comment: Will a lambda expression work within that instance of viewmodel? Fairly new to learning MVC so forgive any stupidity.

Comment: `modelItem => item.Cart.Qty` doesn't work in the first place because the property is named `Carts` not `Cart`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking your view you want to display "SweetName" and "Qty".

So for this you have to re structured your "SweetViewModel" like

```
public class SweetViewModel
    {
        //From Sweet Model
        public int SweetID { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public string SweetName { get; set; }
        public bool Singular { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        //From Cart Model
        public int Qty { get; set; }
    }
```

And depending upon your output you have to design your view like

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.ViewModels.SweetViewModel>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>SweetTestArea</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="table">    
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SweetID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SweetName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qty)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

and your controller code will be look like

```
 public ActionResult SweetTestArea()
        {
            List<SweetViewModel> viewModel = new List<SweetViewModel>();

            var q = (from s in db.Sweets
                     join c in db.Carts on s.SweetID equals c.SweetID
                     where c.CartID == "7125794e-38f4- 4ec3-b016-cd8393346669"
                     select new SweetViewModel
                     {
                         CategoryID = s.CategoryID,
                         Description = s.Description,
                         Price = s.Price,
                         Qty = c.Qty,
                         SweetID = s.SweetID,
                         SweetName = s.SweetName
                     });

            viewModel = q.ToList();

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

IF you want left join then your linq query will be

```
var q = (from s in db.Sweets
                     join c in db.Carts on s.SweetID equals c.SweetID into j
                     from c in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where c.CartID == "7125794e-38f4- 4ec3-b016-cd8393346669"
                     select new SweetViewModel
                     {
                         CategoryID = s.CategoryID,
                         Description = s.Description,
                         Price = s.Price,
                         Qty = c.Qty,
                         SweetID = s.SweetID,
                         SweetName = s.SweetName
                     });
```

my suggestion for you that don't use left join because your want to display data in your cart from both of model from Sweet and Cart means there is item in cart with at least 1 qty.

**Edit:**

As i understood upon your last comment you want every item to be display in your cart either its in your cart model or not

So for that

1) let take your cart items first

```
List<SweetViewModel> cart = new List<SweetViewModel>();

            var q = (from s in db.Sweets
                     join c in db.Carts on s.SweetID equals c.SweetID into l
                     from c in l.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where c.CartID == "7125794e-38f4- 4ec3-b016-cd8393346669"
                     select new SweetViewModel
                     {
                         CategoryID = s.CategoryID,
                         Description = s.Description,
                         Price = s.Price,
                         Qty = c.Qty,
                         SweetID = s.SweetID,
                         SweetName = s.SweetName
                     });


            cart = q.ToList();
```

2) then get all sweets and project those into SweetViewModel

```
List<SweetViewModel> allSweets = new List<SweetViewModel>();

            var w = (from s in db.Sweets
                     select new SweetViewModel
                     {
                         CategoryID = s.CategoryID,
                         Description = s.Description,
                         Price = s.Price,
                         Qty = 0,
                         SweetID = s.SweetID,
                         SweetName = s.SweetName
                     });

            allSweets = w.ToList();
```

3) Filter out those sweets that are present in cart
   You'll get sweet id in below filtered list

```
var filteredSweets = allSweets.Select(x => x.SweetID).Where(x => !cart.Select(y => y.SweetID).Contains(x)).ToList();
```

4) Add those filtered sweets in to view model

```
List<SweetViewModel> viewModel = new List<SweetViewModel>();

            foreach (var i in filteredSweets)
                viewModel.Add(allSweets.Where(x => x.SweetID == i).Take(1).SingleOrDefault());
```

5) Then add your cart items into view model

```
viewModel.AddRange(cart);
```

and return this view model to view.

you can use order by to sort items in cart as your need.

Comment: This is so close, changing the viewModel to your suggestion makes more sense and allows me to select the Qty in the view now. The query is slightly off, only returning the items to view where items exist in cart. I need all the sweets to be displayed even if that Sweet doesn't exist in cart / Qty is null. Left join on nested query does this but i am unsure on how to write in C#...

Comment: If you want query with left join then its already in solution just take it and implement it in your controller. It may help you

Comment: @DarrenB, don't worry **DefaultIfEmpty()** will do that what you want

Comment: Both of these still only return the sweets that are in cart table with that specific cart ID. In total there are 6 sweets in the Sweet table, which all 6 should be showing. 2 of which exist in the specified CartID, but with the current query it only displays the 2 sweets that exist in the cart. Is it possible to do a left join on a sub query?

Comment: Please view edit section of answer if it helps then please accept answer and vote up

Comment: That has done it :D Been trying to fix this for far too long, thank you ershoaib for all your help!!!!!! I up voted earlier but my reputation isn't high enough to show it... when it is I will be sure to up vote again :D